# MVC4 List all sub folder in folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm try to list all sub folder from another folder in MVC4. I have the following code but it returns the complete path, I just want the folder name.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Gallery()
{
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/Filemanager/userfiles/");
    List<string> picFolders = new List<string>();

    if (Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.jpg").Length > 0)
        picFolders.Add(path);

    foreach(string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        if (Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.jpg").Length > 0)
            picFolders.Add(dir);
    }

    return View(picFolders);
}
```

**CSHTML**

```
@foreach (string picFolders in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @picFolders
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
public ActionResult Gallery()
{
  string path = Server.MapPath(@"path here");
  List<string> picFolders = new List<string>();

  DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);

  if (dirInfo.GetFiles("*.jpg").Length > 0)
    picFolders.Add(dirInfo.Name);

  foreach (var dir in dirInfo.GetDirectories())
  {
    if (dir.GetFiles("*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length > 0)
      picFolders.Add(dir.Name);
  }

  return View(picFolders);
}
```

And dont forget to change the view like this to display the table correctly:

```
@model IEnumerable<string>

<table>
  <tbody>
    @foreach (string picFolders in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @picFolders
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hopes this help you!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

`Directory.GetFiles(path)`

you could use

`new DirectoryInfo(path).GetDirectories()`

this would give you an array of `DirectoryInfo` objects, each with a `Name` and `FullName` property.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
if (Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.jpg").Length > 0)
    picFolders.Add(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(path).Name);
```

and

```
    foreach(string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    if (Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.jpg").Length > 0)
        picFolders.Add(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(dir).Name);
}
```

This will parse out the name from the path and push it into your collection.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the path within [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) object and use the `Name` property.

```
...
foreach(string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        if (Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.jpg").Length > 0)
            picFolders.Add(new DirectoryInfo(dir).Name);
    }
...
```

Or you can use [Path.GetDirectoryName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx) with a little exploit:

```
....
foreach(string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        if (Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.jpg").Length > 0)
            picFolders.Add(Path.GetDirectoryName(dir + "\\e"));
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the last folder name in the path ([credit to this answer by Gabe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521518/c-sharp-equivalent-to-instrrev)):

```
s = s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf("\\", s.Length - 2) + 1)
```

Note this skips a final backslash.  Modify as needed.