# Generic .NET function for VB.NET's InstrRev method

Tags: .net, vb.net

I would like to ask if there is an InstrRev function in .NET that does not depend on the Visual Basic runtime.

Comment: something similar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521518/c-sharp-equivalent-to-instrrev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [String.LastIndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof.aspx) method.

Comment: I think you meant "String.LastIndexOf" ?